# How to use import lib to import file with absolute path?

Tags: python, linux, python-importlib

I am getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/home/USERNAME/PROJECT_DIR/importlibtesttarget'
```

With these files:

##### `/home/USERNAME/PROJECT_DIR/importlibtest.py`

```
import importlib

print(importlib.import_module("/home/USERNAME/PROJECT_DIR/importlibtesttarget.py"))
```

##### `/home/USERNAME/PROJECT_DIR/importlibtesttarget.py`

```
def test_method():
    return "Imported method!"
```

If I write in terminal:

```
less /home/USERNAME/PROJECT_DIR/importlibtesttarget.py
```

I see the contents. SO the path is correct. Is there a problem with using absolute paths? I tried both with and without `.py`.

I need this in order to analyze files in another project, also written in python, using my personal python script.

Comment: copy/paste the results of `ls -l /home/USERNAME/PROJECT_DIR/importlibtesttarget.py` into the body of your question please.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Using `importlib`: (replace `module_name` and `file_path` with their own respective values)

```
import importlib.util
import sys
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[module_name] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

Now you can use `module` as a module

For more info check out the documentation of `importlib` [importing a source file directly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly)